# Select dynamally created element in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Given this HTML table:

```
<table id="#myTable">
  <tr id="#row123"><td>Content</td></tr>
</table>
```

Add in a row with jquery:

```
$('#myTable').prepend('<tr id="#row456"><td>More content</td></tr>');
```

Later on I want to select the `#row456` row that was created. How do I do that?
`$('#row456')` does not work?

Comment: remove the `#` in your html code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `#` from the id when creating the elements in HTML:

```
$('#myTable').prepend('<tr id="row456"><td>More content</td></tr>');
```

`#someid` is the syntax of a jQuery selector selecting the element having `someid` as id ([reference](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)). You also have the same syntax for selection by id in CSS.

Comment: But why does `$("#row123")` work? (the non dynamic row) But the hash causes a problem only on the dynamic inserted row?

Comment: @TonyH It doesn't. `$("#row123")` returns an empty collection if you created the element with `<tr id="#row123"><td>Content</td></tr>`.

Comment: @DenysSéguret It most certainly does for me! The `$('#myTable').prepend()` on `<table id="#myTable">` works for example.

Comment: @TonyH This would be a bug. can you reproduce this behavior in a fiddle ?

Comment: I don't know how to do that sorry. I'm on Firefox 45.0.1  Jquery 2.1.1

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `#` before id

```
$('#myTable').prepend('<tr id="row456"><td>More content</td></tr>');
```

Also your HTML

```
<table id="myTable">
  <tr id="row123"><td>Content</td></tr>
</table>
```